# Отправка файла частями для YandexSpeechKit с помощью curl php

Tags: php, curl, yandex-speechkit

Как с помощью php реализовать загрузку файла для YandexSpeechKit частями?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$new = str_split(file_get_contents(realpath("$file_name")), 1000);
$data = "";
foreach ($new as $now){
         $data .= dechex(strlen($now))."\r\n".$now."\r\n";
}
$data .= "0\r\n\r\n";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: audio/x-pcm;bit=16;rate=16000', "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

попытался сделать это кодом выше, но не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пришлось отказаться от curl, и использовать file_get_contents

```
$new = str_split(file_get_contents(realpath("$file_name")), 2000);
    $data = "";
    foreach ($new as $now){
        $data .= dechex(strlen($now))."\r\n";
        $data .= $now;
        $data .= "\r\n";
    }
    $data .= "0\r\n\r\n";
    $aHTTP = array(
        'http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => ["Content-Type: audio/x-pcm;bit=16;rate=16000", "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"],
                'content' => $data,
                'protocol_version' => 1.1,
                'follow_location' => 1
            )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```